# Negative HTTP_HOST match in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to deny access to a folder, unless it is on two specific subdomains. Having a bit of a time getting it to work. Here is what I am trying, which works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^allowed.subdomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(hidden) - [F,L]
```

When I add the second subdomain it fails to work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^allowed.subdomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^secondallowed.subdomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(hidden) - [F,L]
```

So that the `hidden` folder is forbidden on all domains, except  `allowed.subdomain.com` and `secondallowed.subdomain.com`

Comment: I assume what is happening upon visiting `secondallowed.subdomain.com` it matches the first negation, because the url is not `allowed.subdomain.com` and is then forbidden. Struggling figuring out an alternate way to achieve the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below rule I am assuming `subdomain.com` is same for both the subdomains,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(allowed|secondallowed).subdomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(hidden) - [F,L]
```

Comment: They are not the same. I'd like to avoid any complicated regexs to keep this on one line, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^allowed.subdomain.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^secondallowed.subdomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(hidden) - [F,L]
```

This appears to work, if anyone would like to provide a better explanation how the `[OR]` operator works here as opposed to removing it, I will accept that answer :)